# Mesibo Dashboard becomes inaccessible after API call fail

Tags: mesibo

I am trying to create a new user through the backend.

My backend is a spring-boot application Java-based.

The API call end with a JSON object and have the result key set to false, with no other information to understand why the user has not been created. And then, when I tried to refresh the Mesibo dashboard, I got an empty page, with errors in the browser console.

This the user I try to save in Mesibo.

```
{
    "op": "useradd",
    "token": "I put here my app token",
    "user": {
        "address": "newuser@email.com",
        "name": "User Name",
        "token": {
            "appid": "com.fake.id"
        }
    }
}
```

The image shows what I see in the browser console when I try to access It.
[mesibo browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vx36.png)

It is important to note, that the account I use is not mine, I use the one my company gave me.
We are trying to implement our flow, so we are not in prod we are just testing APIs and others...

Thank you very much for your help!

Anas

PS: I created my own account on mesibo and got the same result!

Comment: You are possibly using an expired account (which is not recent) and hence your IP is getting blocked. Hence you are not able to use the console also. If your company account validity is not expired, please send us an email with account details.

Comment: Hi, the account is new, and as I said I also created my own account and tried it. 
Once the API call to create a new user fails, the dashboard becomes inaccessible. 
Ok, I will ask my company to send you credentials over email. 
I will follow the conversation. 
Thank you!

Comment: I could search your account from the name. It was created in Jan and expired after a month. Hence the same result. In any case, please email us and we will help you.

Comment: ok, I will send an email. 
Yes, my account could have expired but my company's one is up to date.

Comment: We replied to your ticket. Thanks!